# login blocked on website

Tags: web, authentication

after working on website run on linxus server and trying to upload a zip file via ftp.
The site has reverted to a old version and now I cannot log in .how can one get around this as I can still log in to server.
thanks 
Andre

Answer (score 0):

Set a new user in the database that i suppose you have, alternatively change the password of an old user. Alternatively alternatively, ask someone who knows what passwords were used in the old version.